# compostition of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=12(8x+3)$

$h(x)=(3x+19)−5$

Solve when $x=8$
I really need step by step directions to solve $f(h(x))$.

Also can someone solve $h(f(x))$.

I really need help this is so confusing. I am able to do the simpler ones but not a question ever this challenging.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(h(x))=f((3x+19)-5)$$

$$=f(3x+14)=12[8(3x+14)+3]$$

$$=12[8\times3x+8\times14+3]=12(24x+112+3)$$

$$=12(24x+115)=12\times24x+12\times115$$

$$=288x+1380.$$

So

$$f(h(8))=288\times 8+1380$$

$$=2684.$$

Comment: @AdamHughes thanks for the cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(h(x))=12(8(h(x))+3)=12[8((3x+19)-5)+3]$